# Accessing variable from Class in Python

Tags: python, variables

How can i print message outside `class EchoBot`?
The problem is, whenever i try to print message outside class it doesn't show up or just show me error that message is not defined.

```
import fbchat

class EchoBot(fbchat.Client):
    def __init__(self,email, password, debug=True, user_agent=None):
        fbchat.Client.__init__(self,email, password, debug, user_agent)

    def on_message(self, mid, author_id, author_name, message, metadata):
        self.markAsDelivered(author_id, mid) #mark delivered
        self.markAsRead(author_id)#mark read



        print("%s said: %s"%(author_id, message))


        if str(author_id) != str(self.uid):
            self.send(author_id,message)



bot = EchoBot("ID", "PASSWORD")
bot.listen()
```

Comment: if you are getting errors, post the calling code and *the full stack trace*

Comment: it is the full code.

Comment: I asked for the calling code AND **the full stack trace**